# Pull photo url from Bestbuy's website in google sheets

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Im trying to make a webscraper, currently im able to pull all the data like price and ram from a laptop. but everything I try to get the main large photo on the website pulls up with nothing, currently I am able to pull the low res photos, but i was hoping for the better quality one

https://www.bestbuy.com/site/asus-11-6-chromebook-intel-celeron-4gb-memory-32gb-emmc-flash-memory-gray-grey/6449513.p?skuId=6449513

I was using this one for example. And i only need the way to pull the url from each scrape not the photo itself. thank you!

Comment: all of them or only the main image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IMAGE(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA(A1)), 
 "where Col1 starts with 'thumbnailUrl:' 
    and Col1 ends with '}'"), """(.+)"""), 3))
```

[image]

change 3 to 1 if you don't need such a big image (just to fit your cell)

add  `limit 1` to query if you need only the main image

Comment: just needed the link so i removed the image part, that worked! thank you!